# MainActivity can't cast interface

Tags: java, android, interface, callback

In `MainActivity` I have interface

```
   public interface MyListener{
        void myMethod(boolean done);
    }
```

but when I trying cast in `onCreate`

```
myListener = (MyListener) this;
```

I got  `java.lang.ClassCastException`

I also have variable in MainActivity:

```
private MyListener mylistener;
```

What I should fix here ?

Comment: Make sure your `MainActivity`  implements your `MyListener` interface

Answer (score 0):

You `MainActivity` must implement your `interface` if you want to do :

```
myListener = (MyListener) this;
```

So your code should be like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyListener {}
```

### EDIT

In your `Fragment` add this :

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

private MyListener mListener;

@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            mListener = (MyListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement MyListener");
        }
    }
```

Then in your `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyListener {
...
@Override
    public void myMethod(Boolean done) {
        //Stuff with this 
    }
```

Comment: if Android Studio generated interface in Fragment, we don't need to implement interface in Fragment but in MainActivity - yes, so if i generate interface in MainActivity I should implement interface in Fragment ?

Comment: check here, he don't implement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51641902/update-textview-in-fragment-from-activity

Comment: In theory you want to modify the views on MainActivity not in Fragment, but if you want to do it, see my answer and do the other way arround

Comment: but I want the opposite, call back from MainActivity to fragment, not a fragment to MainActivity :) way arround give me error